# How to generate two models form relationship Django Admin?

Tags: django, admin, inline, relationship

I have three models (A, B, C), Model B has a FK model A and C, and I want to generate a data entry form to the relation (B).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a model for B you could [set up a ManyToMany between A and C which uses B as the 'through' model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

If you do not already have a model for B, when you set up a regular ManyToMany relation Django will automatically create a Model which has a FK to both A and C. If necessary, you can control which table this auto-generated model uses (so you can tie it into an existing table if necessary).

Typically you only manually define a model like 'B' and use it as a through model if you need to store more data per record than just the FKs to A and C. If all B contains is FKs to A and C its best to let Django auto-generate that model from your [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) field definition.

Comment: Model B is not Django, I did, I build the form for the model B, but I can not add more objects, I can only one to one